# RTL support in textstring property in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I am building a multilingual site and I need support for both LTR and RTL (Arabic) languages. I have managed to find a way to include an alternative CSS to create a RTL version for the tinyMCE control (rich text).

What is the equivalent solution when the property if a simple string (textstring)? How can I define a RTL field? I am talking about the backend (Umbraco)

Thanks,

Themos

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there isn't a built-in means of making document type properties RTL. However, you can 'roll you own' data types and then include them in your document types.

[This article](http://www.nibble.be/?p=50) is a good place to start even though it is several years old. Also, [here](http://www.oshyn.com/_blog/Web_Content_Management/post/Custom_DataTypes_in_Umbraco/).

Answer (score 0):

The best way I came up with for making a RTL textstring, was create a new rich text editor (tinyMCE) datatype, associcate it with a RTL stylesheet, and make the height smaller so it would "look" like a textstring and not a rich text field.